# Как записать значение в Uint8Array как float?

Tags: javascript, типы

Целочисленное пишу так:

```
let value = 16000;
let buffer = new Uint8Array(4);
buffer[0] = 0xFF &(value >>24);
buffer[1] = 0xFF &(value >>16);
buffer[2] = 0xFF &(value >> 8);
buffer[3] = 0xFF & value;
```

Таким образом буфере 0x00, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x80
А как на JavaScript получить float value 0x46, 0x7A, 0x00, 0x00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. Может кому пригодится:

```
let value = 16000;
let float = new Uint8Array(new Float32Array([value]).buffer);
float.reverse(); // реверс порядка байт
```